# Mockito verify works on mock but not on spy

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I have a problem with mockito#spy it does not work.
I have boiled down the problem to this:

```
var list = (ArrayList<String>) Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
var spyList = Mockito.spy(list);

list.add("test");
Mockito.verify(spyList).add("test");
```

Howerver, if I verify on the Mock itself, it does work:

```
var list = (ArrayList<String>) Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
//var spyList = Mockito.spy(list);

list.add("test");
Mockito.verify(list).add("test");
```

I want to use spy on a real object of course, but for the sake of finding my problem, I am using a mock for now.

I am using Junit 5.7.1 and Mockito 3.3.3. Those are pretty much set in stone I'm afraid.

Any suggestion what could be the problem?

Comment: You are never calling `add` on your spy, you are calling it on the mock object. list != spyList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is wrong;
you are attempting to use the Mock object (named list) as a Spy object (which is named spyList).

Try this:

```
spyList.add("test");
Mockito.verify(spyList).add("test");
```

Comment: Damn, I really missed the obvious on this one, didn't I?